# what can i do to change view of Notepad ++ to show green bar after line number

Tags: notepad++, editor

what can i do to change view of Notepad ++ to show me line number which i want right align and after that green vertical bar. Why i am want this as type layout as this gives more distinction between line numbers and right align line number are which gives more easy to read layout

[click here to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBEg3.png)

Comment: The line numbers are already right-aligned in Notepad++. It seems that your example image is NOT one from Notepad++?  Anyway, the only way to get a vertical "green bar" like you want is to have code folding enabled. If you do, then you can set the background color of the fold margin to be green. However, know that the fold margin will not appear until a collapsible block of code is present.

Comment: I am not able to locate from where we can "Enable" code folding, it's default enabled second thing where i can change this fold margin color

Comment: See my answer to both items, below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under `Settings`=>`Preferences`, the fold margin options:
(the **None** option turns off folding, or at least hides the fold margin)

[image]

Under `Settings`=>`Style Configurator`, to change the fold margin color:
Click the `Background colour` square to make the color picker to appear.

[image]